# Google colab memory issue

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I am trying to understand why the following code crashes my Colab session.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


x1 = np.random.rand(90000)

x2 = tf.random.uniform((90000,1)).numpy()

print(x1.shape, type(x1)) 
print(x2.shape, type(x2))

x1 - x2
```

I can see that memory is exploding which causes the crash but I was hoping someone can explain exactly why this is happening. I also understand that this has to do with broadcasting arrays in `numpy` and I am just wondering if this is expected behavior so I can avoid it in the future.

The fix is to `np.squeze(x2, axis=1)` so the vectors have the same shape but clearly there's something I don't understand about what `numpy` is doing under the hood. Any suggestions and clarifications welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x1` has shape `(90000,)`.  `x2` has shape `(90000, 1)`.  In the expression `x1  - x2`, [*broadcasting*](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) occurs (as you suspected), giving a result that has shape `(90000, 90000)`.  Such an array of floating point values requires `90000*90000*8 = 64800000000` bytes.

Comment: Is this how broadcasting should be working? I just assumed ``numpy`` would broadcast both to be vectors. I guess I'll re-read broadcasting in the documentation. Thank you for pointing this out though.

Comment: *"Is this how broadcasting should be working?"*.  Yes, that is exactly how broadcasting is supposed to work.  If you want a result that has just the 90000 pairwise differences, then either `x2` should have shape `(90000,)`, or `x1` should have shape `(90000, 1)`.